# Find if library is compiled by SJLJ or DWARF2 compiler

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dwarf

Is there a way to figure out if a library archive is built using SJLJ or DWARF2 exception handling compiler? The library is compiled using 32 MinGW.

Comment: I think that you could detect a DWARF2 library by searching for either an "eh_frame" or a "debug_frame" section in `objdump -W <filename>`.

Comment: This is good point, Josh. I tied objdump --dwarf library.a and for SJLJ compiled lib it shows no dwarf info, while for DWARF compiled it shows some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with looking for eh_frame. That's an indicator that "DWARF" or "zero-cost" unwinding is in use.

However I'd like to note that it isn't well-formed to ask if a "library" uses this.  Some objects in a library may use o